# C# Windows Form Application Long Button Click

Tags: c#, button, click, piano

Well, so first of all I am pretty new to programming in Windows Form Application, so if I lack knowledge I hope you'll understand.

The program I am currently doing is a virtual piano in Windows Form Application. There are buttons on the screen, each button represent a piano "button", if one is clicked - it plays a sound. Now, what I wanted to know is if there is any way that I can program my piano into detecting a continuous click and play sound until the button is "unclicked". For example, if one keeps on clicking on the "G" chord button it will keep playing the sound until he stops clicking.

If I didn't provide any necessary information I would love to know. Thanks in advance to all the answers.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like say... the MouseDown/MouseUp events?

Comment: I think this is valid question. The _OP_ wants an example of how to detect when a button in pressed and when it is released in order to process these events. An example might help here.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you are looking for is "hold button event".
You could handle the MouseDown and MouseUp events, something like this:

```
private bool buttonDown; 
private void btn1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{ 
    buttonDown = true; 

    int num = 0; 
    do 
    { 
        num++; 
        label1.Text = num.ToString(); 

        Application.DoEvents(); 
    } while (buttonDown); 
} 

private void btn1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{ 
    buttonDown = false; 
}
```

This will starts executing the code when you click the button and keeps executing it until you release the button

Answer (score -1):

You need to use mousedown event. When mouse will enter the button the you need to raise the button click event unit the mouseup event fire.

Comment: Answers should be complete and well thought out. This is simply a comment (I know you don't have enough rep for comments). Please try to post more complete answers that actually show a methodology or solution to the problem asked.

Comment: He said he is pretty new to programming. So I let him to grow by himself, not feeding up.